# EmailEvents - Show domain count and individual emails

Tags: kql

I am trying to write a query that takes an email address and shows a count by domain and then has each individual email address listed under the domain.
I am able to show a count by domain but can't get the individual email addresses to show?

```
EmailEvents
| where RecipientEmailAddress == 'example'
| extend SenderDomain = tostring(split(SenderFromAddress, '@')[1])
| project SenderDomain, RecipientEmailAddress
| summarize SenderCount = count() by RecipientEmailAddress, SenderDomain
| project-reorder RecipientEmailAddress, SenderDomain, SenderCount
| summarize DomainCounts = make_list(pack("SenderDomain", SenderDomain, "SenderCount", SenderCount)) by RecipientEmailAddress
| project RecipientEmailAddress, DomainCounts
| order by RecipientEmailAddress, tostring(DomainCounts) asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what is the expected result, but I think what you are looking for is `make_set` (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makeset-aggfunction)).

Which would give you something like:

```
let EmailEvents = datatable(RecipientEmailAddress:string , SenderFromAddress:string)
[
   "example", "john@contoso.com",
   "example", "jane@contoso.com",
   "example", "dave@microsoft.com",
   "not_example", "C",
];
EmailEvents 
| where RecipientEmailAddress == 'example' 
| extend SenderDomain = tostring(split(SenderFromAddress, '@')[1]) 
| project SenderDomain, RecipientEmailAddress, SenderFromAddress
```

Which outputs:

| SenderDomain | RecipientEmailAddress | SenderFromAddress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| contoso.com | example | john@contoso.com |
| contoso.com | example | jane@contoso.com |
| microsoft.com | example | dave@microsoft.com |

and from here you can continue to your original query:

```
let EmailEvents = datatable(RecipientEmailAddress:string , SenderFromAddress:string)
[
   "example", "john@contoso.com",
   "example", "jane@contoso.com",
   "example", "dave@microsoft.com",
   "not_example", "C",
];
EmailEvents 
| where RecipientEmailAddress == 'example' 
| extend SenderDomain = tostring(split(SenderFromAddress, '@')[1]) 
| project SenderDomain, RecipientEmailAddress, SenderFromAddress
| summarize SenderCount = count(), AllSenderFromAddress = make_set(SenderFromAddress) by RecipientEmailAddress, SenderDomain 
| project-reorder RecipientEmailAddress, SenderDomain, SenderCount 
| summarize DomainCounts = make_list(pack("SenderDomain", SenderDomain, "SenderCount", SenderCount, "Emails", AllSenderFromAddress)) by RecipientEmailAddress 
| project RecipientEmailAddress, DomainCounts | order by RecipientEmailAddress, tostring(DomainCounts) asc
```

| RecipientEmailAddress | DomainCounts |
| --- | --- |
| example | [ { "SenderDomain": "contoso.com", "SenderCount": 2, "Emails": [ "john@contoso.com", "jane@contoso.com" ] }, { "SenderDomain": "microsoft.com", "SenderCount": 1, "Emails": [ "dave@microsoft.com" ] } ] |